# I want to alert if any JSON value changes then update it in the state and then console.log

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for alerting if there is a change in the JSON then it would update state and alert that the data is changed, Unfortunately, this step was looping saying "data changed" though JSON data didn't change.

Here is my code sample

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Api extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)    
        this.state = {
            Old_item: []
        }

    }
    GetCryptoData (){
        const dataURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/";
        fetch(dataURL)
        .then(d => d.json())
        .then(d => {
            if (this.state.Old_item !== d[0]) {
                this.setState({ Old_item: d[0] })
                console.log("data changed");                 
            }

        })

    }

    componentDidMount(nextState) {
        this.GetCryptoData();
        setInterval(this.GetCryptoData.bind(this), 10000);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>                
                {this.state.Old_item.price_usd}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Api
```

Comment: why you use setInterval in componentDidMount?

Comment: you can't compare object like this (this.state.Old_item !== d[0]);;

Comment: So, what will be the right thing? because I want to run the fetch every 10 seconds and alert if anything changed.

Comment: you can use this..

const oldstate= this.state.Old_item[0];
if(oldstate.price_usd !== d[0]["price_usd"]){
//Body
}

Comment: @DAMMAK is right!.

Error is in your comparison

Comment: @SaumyadeepSarkar, I'm not sure what you wanna compare is it every value in the object or just a value.. better yet you can just write a function that compare all the value if they are the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote a function that compare two object value as long as the structure of both object is the same.

although it not full optimized but it can do the job for you.

```js
function compareObject(obj1, obj2) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj1);
  const result = [];
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (obj1[key] === obj2[key]) {
      result.push(1);
    } else {
      result.push(0);
    }
  });
  if (result.indexOf(0) === -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return -1;
}

const a ={
"id": "bitcoin",
"name": "Bitcoin",
"symbol": "BTC",
"rank": "1",
"price_usd": "10326.8374041",
"price_btc": "1.0",
"24h_volume_usd": "24838329700.1",
"market_cap_usd": "184082454924",
"available_supply": "17825637.0",
"total_supply": "17825637.0",
"max_supply": "21000000.0",
"percent_change_1h": "-0.46",
"percent_change_24h": "6.27",
"percent_change_7d": "-11.22",
"last_updated": "1563537331"
};
const b = {
"id": "bitcoin",
"name": "Bitcoin",
"symbol": "BTC",
"rank": "1",
"price_usd": "10326.8374041",
"price_btc": "1.0",
"24h_volume_usd": "24838329700.1",
"market_cap_usd": "184082454924",
"available_supply": "17825637.0",
"total_supply": "17825637.0",
"max_supply": "21000000.0",
"percent_change_1h": "-0.46",
"percent_change_24h": "6.27",
"percent_change_7d": "-11.22",
"last_updated": "1563537331"
};

alert(compareObject(a, b));
```

```
GetCryptoData (){
const dataURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/";
fetch(dataURL)
.then(d => d.json())
.then(d => {
    if (compareObject(this.state.Old_item[0], d[0]) {
        this.setState({ Old_item: d[0] });
    }

})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying to compare two objects. See the below code.

```
let a = {'a':1};
let b = {'a':1};
if(a!==b){
    alert('Not Same!');
}else{
    alert('Same!');
}
```

Do you think they are same? Yes they are for us but for JavaScript they are not because their references are not same when you compare them what JavaScript does is to compare their references.

So, it's better if you can do the comparison or check based on some property from the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do few changes in your current code

1. You do comparison in wrong way. This is not right way to compare array of object. You need to compare keys to check whether the value is change or not
2. setState is asynchronous so console.log may or may not be fire before state is 
   set. So, that's why console should be in the callback of setState.

Your new code is somewhat look as follow

```
class Api extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
        Old_item: []
    }

}
GetCryptoData (){
    const dataURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/";
    fetch(dataURL)
    .then(d => d.json())
    .then(d => {
        if (this.state.Old_item["INDEX"]["YOUR KEY"] !== d["INDEX]["YOUR KEY"]) {
            this.setState({ Old_item: d[0] },()=>{
             console.log("data changed"); 
             })

        }

    })

}

componentDidMount(nextState) {
    this.GetCryptoData();
    setInterval(this.GetCryptoData.bind(this), 10000);
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>                
            {this.state.Old_item.price_usd}
        </div>
    )
}}
export default Api
```

Comment: you need to update the snippet there is a little error... you need to specify the index of the oldState

if (this.state.Old_item[0]["YOUR KEY"] !== d[0]["YOUR KEY"]) {
            this.setState({ Old_item[0]: d[0] },()=>{
             console.log("data changed"); 
             })

Comment: Well, I got the point and Thank you @DAMMAK and Pardeep Sharma but can you tell how I can make this work for chat JSON?

Comment: @SaumyadeepSarkar i don't know what you meant by chat JSON.. can you explain

Comment: although i just wrote a function that compare 2 objects as long as the object structure are the same... it will compare the value...  maybe i will just post it here now

Comment: I have a JSON data of conversations from database which I need to compare if the old_data is changed in the new response of JSON data or not, if yes I want to alert

Comment: @SaumyadeepSarkar if you think that this is correct ans then upvote this ans

Answer (score 0):

Like every one above is mentioning, you can't compare objects like that. Because objects are not primitive literals. Meaning they are passed by reference not by value. In simple terms

```
let obj1 = { a: 1 };
let obj2 = { a : 1 };

obj1 !== obj2;
```

So I typically use different functions of my own to compare objects. If you only need to do a shallow compare then the following simple function will suffice. If you need more than a shallow compare then you will need a more complex function.

```
const areObjectsEqual = (obj1 = {}, obj2 = {}) => Object
  .keys(obj1).length === Object.keys(obj2).length
  && Object.keys(obj1).every(key => obj1[key] === obj2[key]);
```

Instead of using:

> if (this.state.Old_item !== d[0])

Just do

> if (!areObjectsEqual(this.state.Old_item, d[0])

If the issue still persists it might be due to the objects being deeply nested or due to async nature of state. So you will have to look at those factors.